# SPF alignment with subdomains

Tags: email, mandrill, spf, return-path

I'm trying to set up a Return-path for Mandrill emails. This is what I currently have:

```
From: hello@info.example.com
Return-path: bounce-mc.us3_25014995.932533-27c52c08ee@mail52.suw11.mcdlv.net
```

and I'm wondering how to set up the **Return-path** header. Would it pass the SPF alignment if the Return-path would be the following:

```
From: hello@info.example.com
Return-path: hello@bounce.example.com
```

?

I've found this: https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/spf/spf-alignment which mentions couple of examples about SPF alignment but I can't find anywhere in the SPF standard whether if I have subdomains both in the **From** & **Return-path** if that'd align just based on top of the top-level *example.com* domain.

I'm unfortunately not able to set up the **Return-path** to match the **From** like so:

```
From: hello@info.example.com
Return-path: hello@info.example.com
```

As I can't create a CNAME record for *info.example.com* as I already have an MX record for this subdomain to route incoming emails to Gsuite (see this issue: https://support.google.com/a/forum/AAAA034zvV85E_AluPsqD8/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2FApps%2F5E_AluPsqD8%2F0x_O1tqmAwAJ&msgid=0x_O1tqmAwAJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sender, you don't set a return path. That's the job of the receiving server. As [RFC5321 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.4):

> A message-originating SMTP system SHOULD NOT send a message that
> already contains a Return-path header field.  SMTP servers performing
> a relay function MUST NOT inspect the message data, and especially
> not to the extent needed to determine if Return-path header fields
> are present.  SMTP servers making final delivery MAY remove Return-
> path header fields before adding their own.

The envelope sender is what's used in the `MAIL FROM` SMTP command, and that's what SPF checks. SPF *does not* look at what's in the `from` address header – one of its weaknesses – but fortunately exactly what DMARC is designed to (ahem) address. That MX Toolbox article is misleading because it categorises this alignment as an SPF feature when it's a DMARC one, which is why you're not finding it in the SPF spec.

If mandrill is expected to handle your bounces while maintaining [DMARC (relaxed) alignment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-3.1), I would expect your envelope sender to be something like:

```
bounce-mc.us3_25014995.932533-27c52c08ee@mandrill.example.com
```

and then you'd have a CNAME in your domain's DNS pointing it at mandrill:

```
mandrill CNAME mail52.suw11.mcdlv.net
```

Comment: I probably made myself a little unclear then. I'm trying to instruct Mandrill to set the envelope from for me as per the instructions here: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582727-How-to-Customize-the-Return-Path-Address.

And I'm wondering when I set it as outlined in my question if it'll pass the DMARC checks.

Comment: That mostly lines up with what I said. Mandrill wants your CNAME to point directly at `mandrillapp.com` rather than the `mcdlv.net` hostname, and they want you to use the custom header `X-MC-ReturnPathDomain` to pass the domain, which acts as an override for the actual envelope sender you're submitting with, or to apply one globally from your account settings.

Comment: I understand that, however, my question is: is it fine to have
From: hello@info.example.com
Return-path: hello@bounce.example.com?

Is that going to cause any authentication issues as the subdomains don't match.

Comment: No, but you can implement this a different way to make the alignment work: Use `hello@info.example.com` as the from address, and then `hello@bounces.info.example.com` as your `X-ReturnPathDomain`, and be sure to configure a "relaxed" DMARC policy.

Comment: Right, that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSvoboda can you mark this as answered, & correct answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add an example to your conversation. After reading your comments, I've noticed that Goodreads apply the same pratice as Synchro mentioned. See here: [Goodreads-Return-Path](https://content.screencast.com/users/onursomeka/folders/Snagit/media/8a6fe252-f487-4cec-b840-f11148a980f5/goodreads-mail-example.png)